# didSelectRowAtIndexPath and segues

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, segue

I am working with Storyboard. I am in doubt regarding the use of segues when pushing a new UItableViewController onto the navigation stack. How to do it right? No segue when the push results from a tap in a cell and just use didSelectRowAtIndexPath?
Please share your opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not mention it at all, but judging by your mention of a `segue` you are using storyboarding.

When using storyboarding there is a new way to show a new view controller. By connecting a `UITableViewCell` using a seque to a new view controller in Interface Builder. When you do that, there's no need to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` because the new view controller will be displayed automatically. You can however prepare your `segue`, and set parameters on the new view controller for example:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // assumes only one type, more extensive checking before cast to 
    // make it safer is needed.
    MyViewController *viewController = (MyViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;

    viewController.detailObject = myModelObject;
}
```

For any tableview cell that is not connected using a segue you can provide your own behaviour using plain old `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

There is no correct way, just use whatever seems easiest to you.

Comment: But how do you find the object at selected index?

Comment: `[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];`

Comment: How does it know to use the segue or the code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?