# how to load different data into the table view from different arrays depending on what row is clicked using storyboards on iOS7?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7, uistoryboardsegue

I am learning `iOS` development and working on sample `iOS` application. I got some doubts in `UITableView`, I wish to load different data into the table view from different arrays depending on what row is clicked. I done this using xcode 4 with nib files, I have written `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method in implementation file

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PetsTableViewController *pets = [[PetsTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PetsTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    if([[petsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]isEqual:@"Dog"]) {
        pets.petsInt = 0;
        [pets setTitle:[petsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    if([[petsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]isEqual:@"Cat"]) {
        pets.petsInt = 1;
        [pets setTitle:[petsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    if([[petsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]isEqual:@"Snake"]) {
        pets.petsInt = 2;
        [pets setTitle:[petsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pets  animated:YES];
//    [pets release];
}
```

this is the sample code, here i declared dog, cat, snake arrays in table 1. When i clicked any of this row it should display

dog -> dog1, dog2, dog3 arrays with each row in a different table (table 2).

How to do this using storyboard with xcode 5 ? (using segues )

Please share your thoughts about it

Comment: possible duplicate of [didSelectRowAtIndexPath and segues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191619/didselectrowatindexpath-and-segues)

Comment: You could use contentView of tableViewCell to show up your array depending on which row is clicked or tapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me simplify your code

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PetsTableViewController *pets = [[PetsTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PetsTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    if([petsArray[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Dog"]) {
        pets.petsInt = 0;
        [pets setTitle:petsArray[indexPath.row]];
    }
    if([petsArray[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Cat"]) {
        pets.petsInt = 1;
        [pets setTitle:petsArray[indexPath.row]];
    }
    if([petsArray[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Snake"]) {
        pets.petsInt = 2;
        [pets setTitle:petsArray[indexPath.row]];
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:pets  animated:YES];
}
```

Second, if you want to init a controller that you've created on storyboard, you should use this line of code:

`PetsTableViewController *pets = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PetsTableViewController"];`

Remember to set your storyboard ID

Third, if you want the pushed view controller to display dog1, dog2, dog3 on table, you could make a `NSArray` property in `PetTableViewController.h`, then use it as normal.

Fourth, your code should works fine, you don't need to use segue in this case.
However, if you want to use segue, just open your storyboard and click on your prototype `UITableViewCell` and Ctrl-Drag it to the `PetTableViewController`, set segue to Push.

In your controller, implement `prepareForSegue` method, set your `petArray` for `destinationViewController` and that's it.

//--------------------------------------
Update:

1. You setup your `PetViewController` in storyboard wrong, delete it and add another `UITableViewController`
2. You forget to set `Storyboard ID` in your `MainStoryboard`, so this line will not work
   `PetsTableTableViewController *pets = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PetsTableTableViewController"];`

Try to find it in storyboard.

1. Don't drag `UITableViewCell` to `PetViewController` (i was wrong, because i used this only once). Instead, drag `ViewController` to `PetViewController`.
   If you do this properly, then these lines of code should work fine:

   ```
   PetsTableTableViewController *pets = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PetsTableTableViewController"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:pets  animated:YES];
   ```

or by using segue

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showListDetails"])
    {
        PetsTableTableViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        [destViewController setPetsInt:selectedIndex.row]; //selectedIndex is a class variable of NSIndexPath
    }
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedIndex = indexPath;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showListDetails" sender:self];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, here is my sample code https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwyjk1QbhhGGb3lBcURPUlNKNnM/edit?usp=sharing  its showing some thread related exceptions how to clear this ?

Comment: Thank you I will try to do this using storyboards :)

Comment: Hi, I just done this using storyboard in xcode 5, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwyjk1QbhhGGb3lBcURPUlNKNnM/edit?usp=sharing  here is the files. I tried to follow your answer regarding this question but i couldn't able to find the exact solution getting some exceptions. I also tried with segues method. can you please look into it ? thank you.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwyjk1QbhhGGRTRMVWN5ZkM2R28/edit?usp=sharing  here is the code

Comment: That's quick, Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to call html files depends on array item clicked in table view, I created View controller with webview in storyboards and made push connection with table view(PetsTableTableViewController). Created  new files for webview (PetsWebViewController). In PetsWebViewController i have written-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:htmlFile ofType:@"html"]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];

}

Comment: also written segue method in PetsTableViewController, The html files not calling can you please look into my code , https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwyjk1QbhhGGaWpCeFVoVS1JWWM/edit?usp=sharing  . Please let me know how to do this. Thanks

Comment: you're doing it wrong, read the document first before asking. `NSURLRequest` and `UIWebViewController` are for different purposes.