# Segue when the `UITableViewCell is tapped in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, cell

This is my first time trying this and I just can't figure it out. Ive read many questions like this but none seem to work so if somebody could please explain how to segue to a detail view when cell tapped on I would be so grateful!

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return names.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let LECell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LocalPostsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LocalPostsTableViewCell

    imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in
        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

            LECell.postImage.image = downloadedImage
        }
    }


    LECell.postName.text = names[indexPath.row]
    LECell.postLocation.text = locations[indexPath.row]
    LECell.postDate.text = dates[indexPath.row]



    return LECell
}

let localPostsDetailSegue = "showLocalPostsDetailView"

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == localPostsDetailSegue {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? LocalPostsDetailViewController {
            if let postIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow[indexPath.row] {
                destination.postName = names[postIndex]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [didSelectRowAtIndexPath and segues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191619/didselectrowatindexpath-and-segues)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For that you need to implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method of `UITableView`. Please see the below code:

First of all take the global variable:

```
var currentIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    currentIndexPath = indexPath
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showLocalPostsDetailView", sender: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == localPostsDetailSegue {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? LocalPostsDetailViewController {
            destination.postName.text! = names[currentIndexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok i did that but the second to last line if prepareForSegue is giving me an error, use of unresolved identifier indexPath. I know what it means but don't see why its happening

Comment: @m1234 ok got the problem! Wait I will update the answer

Comment: Alright that seems to be working better. The only issue is now there is an error on lat line "Cannot subscript a value type [String]"

Comment: What's the type of "postName" and "names" variables?

Comment: names is an array of strings and postName is a UILabel

Comment: @m1234 Check the edited answer! `destination.postName.text! = names[currentIndexPath.row]`

Comment: That worked! Sort of. The error were gone so i ran on the simulator and got an uncaught exception on the last line saying found nil while unwrapping optional value. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @m1234 I hope you don't have nil values under names?

Comment: Names is accessed from an object stored in Parse and when you create a post you cannot save it without a name so it can't be

Comment: @m1234 Where you are getting the error? In Next `UIViewController`?

Comment: In the last line of prepareForSegue. It is set up identical to your answer

Comment: @m1234 Can you please print the value for `names[currentIndexPath.row]` and please check you are getting the value or not?

Comment: When I comment out destination.eventName.text! = names[currentIndexPath!.row] and print instead I get the same error, I assume that means I am not getting the Value? Thanks for all your help by the way!

Comment: @m1234 If you will start getting the value then the issue will be solved!

Comment: Alright Ill figure that out! Thats again! I will update your answer as answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what exactly you're asking because your question is very broad. Whether or not you have the programming set up right to transfer the information to the detail view, the actually act of switching to the detail view is done by simply control dragging/right click dragging from the cell its self on the storyboard to the ViewController used to display the information, then select the show option. Just be sure that your table view have a navigation controller. If it doesn't, you can just select the TabelViewController, then at the top, click editor, embed in, navigation controller. This will automatically put a back button on the top left for returning to the table view when done in the detail view. I'm not sure if this was what you were looking for, but I hope that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the indexPath, that's done for you by the tableView:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? LocalPostsDetailViewController,
        let selectedIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        destination.postName = names[selectedIndex]
    }
}
```